# How to return all result rows resulting from a SQL statement execution to the page where the AJAX request came from

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, arrays

How to fetch all result rows in MySQL+PHP?

You know, if I use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`  , it only returns one result row as an associative array. I am using AJAX to fetch the data in a MySQL table.

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from questions where announcementid='$taskid'")or die(mysql_error());
```

How to return the value of $result which is an array to the page where an Ajax request was fired?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // fetch the results from mysql
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ); 

    // output them, encoded as a javascript object
    echo json_encode( $row );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

You can then access the data as an array in your javascript code on the client side.

Comment: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  [json] (json_encode_r) type is unsupported, encoded as null.

Comment: are you sure $result is an array of results and not the resource handle used to access those results?

Comment: $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ); echo json_encode( $row );

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add a `while` function to the PHP code, and do the same that [rikh suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769302/496830):

```
$results = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

// output them, encoded as a javascript object
echo json_encode( $results );
```